# MaxFileSize Issue while using SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

i have defined below configuration with **10KB** still i could see new logs are appending to existing log file after 20KB. I was expecting if logs size increase more than 10KB then automatically old logs will be achieved.
Below is my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
<artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
<version>1.3.0-alpha5</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is my logback.xml

```
<configuration debug="true">
<property name="logPath" value="${LOG4J_LOG_PATH}"/>
<appender name="FILE-ROLLING" 
class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">    
<file>${logPath}/zapp-info.log</file>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">            <fileNamePattern>${logPath}/archived/zapp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>10KB</maxFileSize>
        </SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy>
        <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern> %d %-5level %t %c{0} %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="com.zinier.common.util" level="debug" additivity="true">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
</logger>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
</root>
```

Below Logs on the console.

```
1:00:57,545 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@7f560810 - Roll-over at midnight.
11:00:57,557 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@7f560810 - Setting initial period to Tue Nov 05 23:32:59 IST 2019
11:00:57,587 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE-ROLLING] - Active log file name: /Users/znrind-a0053/Downloads/logs/zapp-info.log
11:00:57,587 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE-ROLLING] - File property is set to [/Users/znrind-a0053/Downloads/logs/zapp-info.log]
11:00:57,589 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler@1b0375b3 - Attaching appender [FILE-ROLLING] to Logger[ROOT]
11:00:57,603 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor@ae45eb6 - End of configuration.
11:00:57,604 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@6f7fd0e6 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
11:00:57,609 |-INFO in c.q.l.co.rolling.helper.RenameUtil - Renaming file [/Users/znrind-a0053/Downloads/logs/zapp-info.log] to [/Users/znrind-a0053/Downloads/logs/archived/zapp.2019-11-05.0.log]
11:00:57,755 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.helper.TimeBasedArchiveRemover - first clean up after appender initialization
11:00:57,758 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.helper.TimeBasedArchiveRemover - Multiple periods, i.e. 32 periods, seem to have elapsed. This is expected at application start.
```

Comment: Do you see a message like this in the console when the logger is initialized?
`13:50:14,418 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1911728085 - Archive files will be limited to [10 KB] each.`. If yes, then is the log file getting rolled over or not? If getting rolled over but not rolled over when reached the 10KB size then most likely the reason is you are logging more frequently (i.e. By the time logback rolling over the file, more information is logged to the log file). If that is the case, you may need to increase the file size a bit more.

Comment: Didn't see such messages on the console. But files are getting rolled over everyday. Yes i am frequently logging to file for testing purpose. i have increased the file sizes to 10MB for further observation. I will post the update if file rolled over after reached 10MB.